# Find the preceding text following by a certain number in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, find-and-replace

I have a database in spreadsheets which has two versions, `with flag` and `without flag`. Data with flags have preceding characters (e.g. MDL, <, ND, etc.)

This is part of the **with flag** sheet:

[image]

And here's same part for the **without flag** sheet:

[image]

I am getting my statistics from `without flag` sheet (because only numbers can be included in the formulas). But I am trying to figure out if the statistics that I got from the `without flag` (i.e. minimum, mean, max, etc.) was flagged originally. If yes, what's the flag?

For the first part, I can just compare the statistics from two sheets, and if they are different, it means that it was flagged.

**Question:** How I can find out what was the flag? (e.g. MAX, <, R, etc.)

There are more than 15 different flags. I also prefer doing it in excel formulas for sake of simplicity as this spreadsheet till now had not needed any macro.

I am thinking about something like finding the cell that the numeric part of it matches with the statistics and then extracts the non-numeric part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Substitute`, which will search for one string inside another and replace it.

```
=SUBSTITUTE('with flag'!DI207,'without flag'!DI207,"")
```

We're simply stripping out the numeric portion, which is in `'without flag'!DI207`, and replacing it with a "", to leave only the flag. This also serves to indicate whether there is a flag or not - any non-blank return indicates there was a flag there.